# Extract value of element in XML with xmlstarlet

Tags: xmlstarlet

My situation is very specific, and I am a beginner with **xmlstarlet**.

I have an XML file like the one below, which contains hundreds of entries.

```
<netbooks>
  <file id="2">
    <date>2008-06-04 16:40</date>
    <author>Daniel</author>
    <name bytes="422904" hash="383a39b183">New name of - Just an example.pdf</nome>
    <name bytes="383135" hash="5a43dc3524">Just an example.pdf</nome>
  </file>
</netbooks>
```

Where **root** = netbooks tag.

**QUESTIONS**

1. I have the file hash `5a43dc3524`, i want to take the **value** of **date**, that is `2008-06-04 16:40`. What's the easiest way to do this?
2. Also, how to get the **attribute** `id` (that is `2`) from **file** element? Again, I have the hash, just it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have the file hash 5a43dc3524, i want to take the value of date, that is 2008-06-04 16:40. What's the easiest way to do this?

We can get the date using the xpath expression `//file[name/@hash="5a43dc3524"]/date/text()`. Assuming that the file `data.xml` contains the sample data from your question, if we run:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//file[name/@hash="5a43dc3524"]/date/text()' data.xml
```

We get the output:

```
2008-06-04 16:40
```

The expression `//file[name/@hash="5a43dc3524"]/date/text()` means "find all the `<file>` elements that contain a `<name>` element in which the value of the `hash` attribute is `5a43dc3524`. For each `<file>` element, get the value of the contained `<date>` element and return its text value.

> Also, how to get the attribute id (that is 2) from file element? Again, I have the hash, just it.

We can do something very similar:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//file[name/@hash="5a43dc3524"]/@id' data.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Xmlstarlet --help is pretty bad. Do you know any site with good documentation or friendly tutorial to point me to?

Comment: Search for "introduction to xpath" and you will find many, many articles with information about writing xpath expressions. I don't have any specific recommendations that I think are better than others.

Comment: There are quite a lot of `xmlstarlet` Q&A here too

Comment: @roaima yes, i have saved many of these answers too.

Comment: @daniel: `xmlstarlet select --help`?